# Password encryption deycrption UTF8 Encoding String conversion doesn't work

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, encryption, utf-8

I wanna save a password encrypted in a local database (on windows phone). For that I first have to encrypt the password with this.

```
byte[] passwordInByte = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(clearPW);
byte[] protectedPasswordByte = ProtectedData.Protect(passwordInByte, null);
return UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(protectedPasswordByte, 0, protectedPasswordByte.Length);
```

When I use this I get the encyrpted password like this:

"\0賐�ᔁᇑ窌쀀쉏\0쐮�毸䉯놜侫䅛\0\0\0\0昐\0Ā\0 \0⎛폳띪ꌾၜჸ㸴뀲േꞪ賂ﯛ䎳웠姒\0\0耎\0Ȁ\0 \0ｔƽ팃ல�쿄갗ꪄ᫓\0꒱௴贒⊡噷�ʥ魚@\0챞Ċ뽨뒸縉菒Æ�≁ᦹ諻⋤떵孵ר䒹춳✴頻ľ�뚿㠔꾹놼ɝ⍔"
And the protected passwordPasswordByte is has a length of 230 bytes.

My decryption function looks like this:

```
byte[] encryptedBytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encrytpedPW);
byte[] passwordByte = ProtectedData.Unprotect(encryptedBytes, null);
return UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(passwordByte, 0, passwordByte.Length);
```

Now the enycrptedBytes array is 290 bytes length and the password cannot be even decrypted because the Unprotect function throws the error "Invalid data"

But everything works fine in case I use the Convert.BaseString64 functions like this:

encryption:

```
byte[] passwordInByte = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(clearPW);
byte[] protectedPasswordByte = ProtectedData.Protect(passwordInByte, null);
return Convert.ToBase64String(protectedPasswordByte, 0, protectedPasswordByte.Length);
```

decryption:

```
byte[] encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encrytpedPW);
byte[] passwordByte = ProtectedData.Unprotect(encryptedBytes, null);
return UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(passwordByte, 0, passwordByte.Length);
```

Does anybody of you has an idea what is so wrong about the UTF8 encoding? Because the first way is the recommended was by MSDN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just don't do this:

```
return UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(protectedPasswordByte, 0, protectedPasswordByte.Length);
```

Firstly, I'd strongly advise using `Encoding.UTF8` instead of `UTF8Encoding.UTF8`, for clarity. That won't fix the problem, but it's a good habit to get into - the `UTF8` property is declared on `Encoding`, not `UTF8Encoding`, so it's clearer to acknowledge that.

The main problem is that you've just not got text data. You shouldn't use `Encoding.GetString` when the binary data you've got isn't regular encoded text data. You've got arbitrary binary data which doesn't represent text (until it's decrypted).

Base64 is precisely designed to represent *any* binary data in ASCII text - so you don't end up losing any data due to binary data which simply doesn't have any "straight" text representation in whatever encoding you decide to use. You should use Base64 - or hex, or something similar - any time you want to encode arbitrary binary data as text.

Comment: I'm sorry. The Unicode was just a single try and the error also occured (as you mentioned it) in case of UTF8. I change it in the question.